# Outbound SMTP from GitHub Actions is blocked. How to address?

Tags: smtp, github-actions

I have a unit test that sends mail and then checks to see if the mail was delivered. It works fine on my laptop but it doesn't run as a GitHub action. It appears that GitHub actions are blocking outbound port 587 to my SMTP server.

Is there a simple work-around to this? Right now I'm just disabling the unit test when it runs on GitHub. This works, but it means that my code coverage goes down.

EDIT: It has been suggested in the comments that I use a mock SMTP server. That won't let my unit-test run unless there is some way to validate that the message was delivered. So I think that I would also need a mock IMAP server. And unfortunately, `go-smtp-mock` does not provide authentication support.

However, a neat idea would be to bring up a local server and IMAP server within the GitHub actions VM. Hm...

Comment: Tons of mock SMTP servers are out there for unit testing, like https://github.com/mocktools/go-smtp-mock.

Comment: I don't want a mock SMTP server. I want a real smtp server! Are you suggesting I run a local SMTP server and a local IMAP server and run all of the self-tests self-contained?

Comment: @LexLi - Thanks. However, `go-smtp-mock` does not include a mock IMAP server as well. But the idea of bringing up an smtp and imap server together is a fascinating idea.